# MS Flexgrid extension in CodedUI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a MSFlexgrid in my application where i have rows and columns and I tried to automate using CodedUI. And I am trying to spy the cells inside the MSFlexGrid but CodedUI is unable to spy the cells and it shows as below when tried to spy the cells it shown as Client as a ControlType. So, please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

That's an ActiveX control.  I don't think Coded UI has built in support.  You can try the options here [MSDN SOCIAL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a41a0628-0207-46d4-86a2-c2ddf65135e7/coded-ui-activex-controls?forum=vsautotest)

1. First option, not very reliable, click the grid control in specific coordinates. It will work if you always have to select the top row and the grid sise doesn’t change rapidly.
2. The second option, much better functionality requires a lot of effort. You will have to wrap the grid control with a shell that implements an accessibility API to make it testable. It is a lot of work and I wouldn’t have suggested the first option if it wasn’t so difficult.